# cannot access one folder on remote pc

Tags: windows, networking

I have a small network with ~5 PC's.
On Server-PC I have 5 shared folders.

From my pc I cannot access `\\Server-PC\SharedFolder3`.

I tried to turn off and on network discovery, unshared the folder and reshared...

Still the same problem: "Windows can't access `\\Server-PC\SharedFolder3`".

Can anyone help me out?
PS Server-PC has a LAN connection and my computer has Wireless connection

Comment: it wasn't the firewall, other shared folders can be accessed. Just posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution...

I was checking the permission on that specific folder and it was missing the "everyone" user. Added it, checked the needed rights and now it can be accessed.